# An application of Baire 's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Definition :  Let $S$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. A point $x \in S$ is called an isolated point if $\exists \varepsilon >0 $ s.t $B(x,\varepsilon) \cap S \setminus \{x\}= \emptyset. $

Baire's Theorem : Let $ (X,d)$ be a complete metric space. Then, the interior of any countable union of closed subsets is nonempty implies the interior of one of the closed subsets is nonempty as well.

With the theorem and the definiton in mind, I am supposed to prove the following;
Propositon : If $X$ is  a complete metric space which has $\textbf{no}$ isolated points, then $X$ is uncountable.

I wrote down as follows :
By having no isolated points , we have $\forall x \in X, \quad \forall \varepsilon> 0  \quad B(x,\varepsilon) \cap X\ \{x\} \ne \emptyset.$
And  I assume the assertion of the proposition is false. In other words, $X $ is countable and it can be rewritten as  $X= (S^c) \cup S$ for some $S^c $ which is countable and and $S = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is uncountable and each $S_n$ is closed. I somehow must try to get a contradiction with the Baire's Theorem. But I could not. Help me if my starting point is wrong and if it is guide me to another direction.

Comment: Nitpicking: You should also say that $ X$ is not empty.

Comment: We can show by very elementary means that a non-empty complete metric space with no isolated points has a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set. But it's much longer than  Brian M. Scott's answer to your Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Turn it around: show that if $X$ is a countable metric space without isolated points, then $X$ is not complete. Suppose, then, that $X$ is a countable metric space without isolated points.

- Show first that $X$ must be countably infinite.

Thus, we can enumerate $X=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

- Show that each singleton set $\{x_n\}$ is closed and has empty interior.
- Use the Baire category theorem and the fact that $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{x_n\}$ to show that $X$ is not complete.

Comment: If the space is not complete how does baire theorem in my question help?(i do not know about cathegory theorem). You re suggesting me that i use the other direction of the baire theorem?

Comment: @Quantes: *Baire category theorem* is the more common name of what you called simply the Baire theorem: it’s the same theorem. You use it to show that if $X$ were complete, $X$ would be a counterexample to it.

Comment: Ok. I will try it. Thank you so much

Comment: @Quantes: You’re welcome; feel free to ask for more help if you get stuck.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was sort of under the impression that the "countable intersection of open dense sets in a complete metric space is dense" theorem is called Baire's theorem, and the "Complete metric spaces are of the second category" theorem is Baire Category Theorem. Is this not the case? Obviously the latter is a direct and trivial consequence of the former, but still.

Comment: @David: For me the term *Baire category theorem* covers all of the variants, including the ones for locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sure, I guess if they all stem from the same idea that should work

Comment: We don't need to prove initially that $X$ is infinite. Only assume that $X$ is not empty and countable, so that $X=\{x_n:n\in  \mathbb N\}.$  It does not matter whether $x_n=x_m$ for some distinct $n,m.$....$\{ \{x_n\} :n\in \mathbb N\}$ is still a countable family of closed nowhere-dense sets.

Comment: I 'm almost done. Here what i did. Based on @user254665's suggestion, I take $X$ to be countably infinite. By using  no isolated point property, i proved each singleton set is closed. Then I got the contradiction By using Baire's thm $X$ is not complete. Is it true that ' no isolated property' is needed to prove that each singleton is closed?

Comment: Singletons are closed in any metric space. The main thing is that  singletons of $X$ are not open, because $ \{p\}$ is open iff $p$ is isolated, So a singleton of $X$ is closed and has empty interior.

Comment: So, @user254665 what would cause a problem if we did not assume in the first place that $X$ has no isolated points.? Firstly, any isolated points  $\{ p\} $ in $X$ would be open? Does it mean that it cannot be closed at the same time in this case?

Comment: @Quantes: If $p$ is an isolated point then $\{p\}$ is still closed but it has nonempty interior (specifically, the interior of $\{p\}$ is $\{p\}$).  So then $\{p\}$ is not nowhere-dense and the proof falls apart.  Indeed, it is entirely possible that a complete metric space *with* isolated points can be countable (consider $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: A set can be both open and closed.

Comment: @user254665: I know; I just thought that it was conceptually simpler initially to split the cases.

Comment: @Quantes: Sorry that I wasn’t around earlier today, but it seems that **user254665** was a fine stand-in.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ is a countable subset of $X$ (where $X$ is not empty  and $X$ has no isolated points) then $F=\{\{p\}:p\in Y\}$ is a countable family of closed nowhere-dense sets,  so (Baire) $\cup F$  is co-dense in $X.$ Since $X$ is not empty, therefore $\emptyset \ne X$ \ $\cup F=X$ \ $Y.$ That is, $X\ne Y.$